# Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor

[image]

I found some answers on same query

need update webdriver server with cmd webdriver-manager update ,
Even-though i am getting same error when i start webdriver server with cmd webdriver-manager start.

Answer (score 1):

The error said "port 4444 is busy", so:

1) Change the port to any using `--seleniumPort` option, or

2) It seems to some of webdriver processes are still alive. Close or kill all processes. Use taskmanager or `netstat -ano` to see all using connections and kill them by PID

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Check java is installed or not in your system to use Selenium Standalone java is must. You can check it by using command:
   java --version. If it is not there install the JDK from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/
2. If still you are seeing the issue then check the java and webdriver processes also the port 4444

Thanks,
Prasidh